# error - f was not declared in this scope - secant method

Tags: c++, function, declaration

I am currently working out irr using algorithms through secant method. I think I am doing it correctly so far? but my main problem is that it keeps saying f is not declared in this scope:

```
int fx1 =f (x1);
int fx2 =f (x2);.
```

when i try to declare f as a function it does not allow me to, can anyone help?

```
#include iostream

#include iomanip

#include cmath

using namespace std;

const int Max_Iter=1000;

const double e=0.001; 

     double internal_r(double c, double r, int n){
     double internal_r = 0.0;
     for (n=1; n<=Max_Iter; n++); { 
     internal_r -= c/pow(1.0+r, n);     
     }
     return internal_r;
     } 

int Secant(double x1, double x2, double e, double &root) { 
     
     int fx1 =f (x1);
     int fx2 =f (x2);
 
     if (x1==x2|| f(x2)==f(x1)){
     root=0; return 0; 
     }  
     double x = x1 - f(x1) - (x2-x1) / (f(x2)-f(x1)); 
     if ( fabs(f(x)) < e){
     root = x; return 1;
     } else {
     if (f(x1)*f(x)<0){
        return Secant(x1,x,e,root);
     } else { 
       return Secant (x,x2,e,root); 
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  
     int n = 1; 
     double x1 = 0.0, x2 = 0.0, x = 0.0, fx1 = 0.0, fx2 = 0.0;
     cout << "Secant Method" << endl;
     cout <<"Enter first initial approximation: ";
     cin >>x1;
     cout <<"Enter second initial approximation: "; 
     cin >>x2;
     cout <<"Enter the iteration number: ";
     cin >>n;
     if (n>=0 && n<=Max_Iter) {        
        cout << "you have entered an iteration sucessfully\n";
        x = x1 - (fx1 * (x2 - x1)) / (fx2 - fx1); 
     cout <<"\n The root of the equation is "<< x <<endl; 

     return 0;
      } 
 }
```

Comment: I am getting `<source>:1:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>` Please post your code carefully. Reading [Code and Preformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) is recommended before your start posting questions on SO.

Comment: `for (n=1; n<=Max_Iter; n++); {` appears to have an unwanted semicolon after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: The error is correct - there is no `f()` declared anywhere in this code. What are you expecting that to be?